# How can I add and delete Date objects in arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, vue.js

I'm trying to update a calendar by using the component Datepicker with Vue.js, but I have some problems regarding the adding and deleting of items (in this case, Date objects)

I have already developed two javascript functions: one used for adding new Dates to an array, and another one for deleting specific dates in the same array. The thing is, when the website is loaded, I can perfectly add new dates and delete the dates that initially were created. But what I can't do is to add a new date and then delete it, because with the function I developed, the method used to return the index of the date in the array returns -1.

```
addDate: function(event) {
   var fecha = document.getElementById("inputFecha").value;
   var fecha2 = new Date(fecha);
   availableDates.push(fecha2);
},
deleteDate: function(event) {
   var collection = availableDates,
      d = new Date(event.getFullYear(), event.getMonth(), event.getDate()),
      idx;
   idx = collection.map(Number).indexOf(+d);
   if(idx!=-1){
      availableDates.splice(idx,1);
   }
}
```

And some of the dates I initially created in the same file:

```
var availableDates = [];
availableDates.push(new Date(2019, 2, 29));
availableDates.push(new Date(2019, 2, 30));
availableDates.push(new Date(2019, 2, 28));
```

What I need is the possibility to add and delete without having to recharge the website.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could create a [mcve], so that we can just run the code and reproduce the issue. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552).

Comment: Please show the typical content of `fecha`

Comment: Maybe try something like `availableDates.push(new Date(fecha2.getFullYear(), fecha2.getMonth(), fecha2.getDate()))`

Comment: nevermind - but @StefanBlamberg - that could fix if you are WEST of GMT

Answer (score 0):

When calling `new Date(2019, 2, 30)` the date created is `2019-03-30T00:00:00` *IN YOUR TIMEZONE* ...

<del>whereas, `new Date("30/3/2019")` would create `2019-03-30T00:00:00Z` - i.e. UCT/UTC/GMT/Zulu whatever you call it - if you are not in +0 Timezone, then this will fail</del> Not sure what I was thinking here ... complete and utter garbage :p

If inputFecha is an `<input type="date">`

```
addDate: function(event) {
    var fecha = document.getElementById("inputFecha").valueAsDate;
    var fecha2 =new Date(fecha.getFullYear(), fecha.getMonth(), fecha.getDate());
   availableDates.push(fecha2);
},
```

As you have failed to add an MCVE, the following code is a rough dummy to show that it does work

```js
const availableDates = [];
let something = {
  addDate: function(event) {
    var fecha = document.getElementById("inputFecha").valueAsDate;
    var fecha2 = new Date(fecha.getFullYear(), fecha.getMonth(), fecha.getDate());
    availableDates.push(fecha2);
    console.log(availableDates);
  },
  deleteDate: function(event) {
    var collection = availableDates,
      d // = new Date(event.getFullYear(), event.getMonth(), event.getDate()),
    
    // dummy code to test
    var fecha = document.getElementById("inputFecha").valueAsDate;
    d = new Date(fecha.getFullYear(), fecha.getMonth(), fecha.getDate());
    // end dummy code
    
    const idx = collection.map(Number).indexOf(+d);
    if (idx != -1) {
      availableDates.splice(idx, 1);
    }
    console.log(availableDates);
  }
}
availableDates.push(new Date(2019, 2, 29));
availableDates.push(new Date(2019, 2, 30));
availableDates.push(new Date(2019, 2, 28));
console.log(availableDates);
document.querySelectorAll('.butt').forEach(btn =>
  btn.addEventListener('click', something[btn.id])
);
```

```html
<input type="date" id="inputFecha">
<input type="button" class="butt" id="addDate" value="add">
<input type="button" class="butt" id="deleteDate" value="remove">
```

Comment: Thank you! It totally worked for me. However, I was using an input of type text meanwhile the method ```.valueAsDate```only works for inputs of type date. What I did is:
```var fecha = document.getElementById("inputFecha").value;
var fecha2 =new Date(fecha);
var fecha3 = new Date(fecha2.getFullYear(), fecha2.getMonth(), fecha2.getDate());
availableDates.push(fecha3);
```

And it worked!

Comment: That won't necessarily work, I think it depends on your timezone - so if you want something that is globally consistent you may have issues - honestly, using something like `momentjs` library in such cases is possibly the way to go - you can get far better consistency